# Como saber de qual origem estou executando o Python?

Tags: python

Eu gostaria de saber como eu faço para saber de qual origem eu estou executando o `Python`.

Por exemplo, se eu instalei o Python 3.5 na minha máquina e criei um Virtualenv, como eu poderia saber, através do próprio Python, a origem da execução daquele binário?

Por exemplo, se eu executa `Python`, que saber o caminho completo do executável, como `/usr/bin/python`, por exemplo.

No caso específico, não quero nada referente ao Virtual Env, e sim saber pelo Python o caminho de origem do binário.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `sys.executable`. Assim:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)

# Output '/usr/bin/python'
```

De acordo com a documentação do [sys](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html) Python:

> Uma string que fornece o caminho absoluto do binário executável para o interpretador Python, em sistemas nos quais isso faça sentido. Se o Python não conseguir recuperar o caminho real para seu executável, `sys.executable` retornará uma string vazia ou `None`.